# Sharding MongoDB with 2 VMs

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I'm really new into learning MongoDB and I'm having a hard time trying to understand sharding.
So I have my PC who is the host and I have created two VMs using VirtualBox. In my PC (host) there is a DB with some data. So my issue is which of those 3 components should be the the Config Server, the Shard and the Query Router (mongo). Can somebody please help me explaining this ? (I have read the documentation and still haven't understand it completely).

Answer (score 0):

A sharded cluster needs to run at least three processes, a "decent" sharded cluster runs at least 10 processes (1 mongos Router, 3 Config servers, 2 x 3 Shard servers). In production, they run on different machines, but it is no problem to run them all on the same machine.

I would suggest these steps for learning:

- Deploy a Stand alone MongoDB
- Deploy a Replica Set, see [Deploy a Replica Set](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/) or [Deploy Replica Set With Keyfile Authentication](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set-with-keyfile-access-control/)
- Deploy a Sharded Cluster, see [Deploy a Sharded Cluster](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/#deploy-a-sharded-cluster) or [Deploy Sharded Cluster with Keyfile Authentication](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/deploy-sharded-cluster-with-keyfile-access-control/)

In the beginning it is an overkill to use different machines. Use `localhost` for all.

You can run multiple mongod/mongos instances on one machine, just ensure they are using different ports (e.g. the default port 27017), different `dbPath` and preferable also different log files.

You may run your first trial without authentication. Once you got that working, use authentication with keyfile and as next step use authentication by x.509 certificates.

If you use Windows, then have a look at https://github.com/Wernfried/mongoDB-oneclick